# How to change speed of physics world for particle effects in Sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, particles, skphysicsworld

I created particle effects using the editor but my app is done in all code (Swift). When I change the speed of the physics world, all my physics bodies slow down just fine. But when I make my particles into a physics body, they do not get affected by the speed change even though they should be part of the same physics world. I made the particles be dynamic and affected by gravity and still nothing. I even tried giving them a bitMaskCategory where they do actually get affected by my gravity nodes, however they still don't get affected by physicsWorld.speed .

Anyone have an idea how to do this? I know it's possible but I am missing something. I really don't want to make separate gravity nodes for the particles to mimic the speed of the rest of the world.

Comment: did you set the target of particle?

Comment: last I am aware, both targetNode and physicsbody for particles are broken